# Extending Scala's arrow notation for pairs

Tags: scala

Scala, in `Predef`, defines support for `->` and `→` (here cleaned up a bit):

```
final class ArrowAssoc[A](val __leftOfArrow: A) extends AnyVal {    
    def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(__leftOfArrow, y)
    def →[B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = ->(y)
}
```

This conveniently allows you to create pairs using an arrow notation instead of the plain tuple syntax:

```
scala> "foo" → 42
res0: (String, Int) = (foo,42)
```

This arrow syntax can easily be extended with a type definition and an extractor (here only `→` is shown):

```
type →[A, B] = (A, B)
object → { def unapply[A, B](t: (A, B)) = Some(t) }
```

This allows you to write things like:

```
"a" → 42 match { case a → b ⇒ println(s"found `$a` and `$b`") }
```

and:

```
def foo[A, B](t: A → B) = ???
```

I am wondering if there any reason Scala doesn't define those as well in its standard library. Are there any downsides to these definitions?

Comment: Can't agree more: `->` should be supported in pattern matching. However I think it could also be done using a custom extractor in which case of course the type `A -> B` would still be missing, afaics.

Comment: I'm with Scala on this one—I find that infix extractors hurt readability (and tend to avoid even `->` except in map initialization). If you want it, you can easily define it, but the standard library is already cluttered enough.

Comment: Travis, Scala does have infix extractors for `List`, for example. I am wondering if this is conscious omission, or just something that never made it just because nobody thought of doing it and there were other priorities. If there is any infix notation in the language, I kind of like consistent support. But yeah, not a big deal is anybody can add it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `->` only exists to have an easy to read way to initialize `Map` entries. It's not intended to be a general purpose way to represent pairs. You should use `(a, b)` syntax for all other uses to avoid confusion. As it is, there are already two different ways to represent a pair (`(a, b)` and `Tuple2(a, b)`). We don't need a third.

You might argue that you would want a -> extractor for doing pattern matching on `Map` entries to make it clear which part is the key and which is the value, but remember that `case (key, value)` makes that distinction just as clear. It's only in the case of initialization that there isn't a clear way to distinguish which part is the key and which is the value, other than using `->`.

Comment: I think that you are right that this is the reason why `->` was introduced. But doing so just for tuple creation makes it an incomplete feature. I think the best options would be: 1. Get rid entirely of `->` or 2. Make it consistent across other features (type declarations and pattern matching). I am leaning towards 2 as `->` is already entrenched for creating maps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one downside. Being able to do both

```
def foo[A, B](t: A -> B) = ???
```

and

```
def foo[A, B](t: A => B) = ???
```

would be confusing. If the types don't line up, the compiler would catch it of course. However, only a experienced Scala programmer would understand the error message quickly.

Comment: I am not sure why it is particularly confusing? Scala has `=>`, `->`, and `<-` as a matter of fact. Of course you could argue for removing `->` entirely. I personally like the notation but I realize it's a matter of taste.

Comment: and how about this for comprehension? `def flip(xs:List[A -> B]) = for(a -> b <- xs) yield b -> a` Is that clear? Of course, you could always say "Don't use the `->` in such a case". But as someone who lost the better part of a day to mixing up `->` and anorm's `~>` operator, let me tell you that that kind of confusion can be a real issue. (Granted, the compiler was of no help with `->` vs `~>`).  :(

Comment: Oops, the '`~>`' operator is actually from Spray.io's testkit, not anorm. (Could not get the tests to fail no matter how I broke the code, because with `->` instead of `~>` nothing was actually being tested...)